# Top 5 client performance per month in a date range using linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a table that i need to group by MonthYear (as well as some other columns) and select Top 5 counts per MonthYear for an entire date range.

```
Table | JobKeys  
- Id  
- Branch  
- RegisteredDate  
- ClientReference  
- (Extra Columns not needed for this task)
```

Current group statement:

```
db.JobKeys.Where(o => o.RegisteredDate >= fromDate && o.RegisteredDate <= toDate).GroupBy(o => new{ o.Branch, o.ClientReference, YearMonth = o.RegisteredDate.Year + "/" + o.RegisteredDate.Month }).Select(o => new { o.Key.ClientReference, o.Key.Branch, o.Key.YearMonth, o.Count() })
```

This gives me a full list of how many jobs each client had each month between a date range, however from this list i only want the top 5 clients per each YearMonth.

i.e. At the moment it will return something similar to the following
YearMonth - Branch - ClRef - Count

```
17/05 - Perth - TerryTaylors - 22
17/05 - Perth - TimmyToolies - 33
17/05 - Perth - BillyBobbies - 42
17/05 - Sydney - RinkleRankles - 10
17/05 - Melbourne - PinkyPonkies - 19
17/05 - Melbourne - JanglyJunglies - 11
18/05 - Perth - TerryTaylors - 9
18/05 - Perth - TimmyToolies - 2
18/05 - Perth - BillyBobbies - 1
18/05 - Sydney - RinkleRankles - 15
18/05 - Melbourne - PinkyPonkies - 61
18/05 - Melbourne - JanglyJunglies - 99
```

But i need it to return:

```
17/05 - Perth - TerryTaylors - 22
17/05 - Perth - TimmyToolies - 33
17/05 - Perth - BillyBobbies - 42
17/05 - Melbourne - PinkyPonkies - 19
17/05 - Melbourne - JanglyJunglies - 11
18/05 - Perth - TerryTaylors - 9
18/05 - Perth - TimmyToolies - 2
18/05 - Sydney - RinkleRankles - 15
18/05 - Melbourne - PinkyPonkies - 61
18/05 - Melbourne - JanglyJunglies - 99
```

I can run through a loop to pull out the data from the full dataset but doing so would mean one massive query to start, then looping through an in memory table (theres a fair bit over a million records in the table), Whereas if possible i'd like to pull only the needed data in one query.

Comment: I believe you'd have to at least order by `Count` before selecting top 5, but you won't get the expected result this way

Comment: Hey @MongZhu if i do that, it will only return 5 from the entire listset, i need it for every monthyear in the date range

Comment: have you tried `SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(o => o.Count()).Take(5)).ToList()` instead of `Select(...)`?

Comment: Does the order of your expected result really matter or is the one in my answer good enough?

Comment: @MongZhu as soon as you do your `.Select(...)`, you are now dealing with **one list with all results in it**, so if you apply `.Take(5)` on this, you'll only have 5 results, and not 5 for each `YearMonth`

Comment: @Rafalon you're right. Thanx for the lesson :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public string YearMonth {get;set;}
    public string Branch {get;set;}
    public string CIRef {get;set;}
    public int Count {get;set;}
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Test> Tests = new List<Test>
        {
            new Test
            {
                YearMonth = "17/05",
                Branch = "Perth",
                CIRef = "TerryTaylors",
                Count = 22
            },
            new Test
            {
                YearMonth = "17/05",
                Branch = "Perth",
                CIRef = "TimmyToolies",
                Count = 33
            },
            new Test
            {
                YearMonth = "17/05",
                Branch = "Perth",
                CIRef = "BillyBobbies",
                Count = 42
            },
            new Test
            {
                YearMonth = "17/05",
                Branch = "Sydney",
                CIRef = "RinkleRankles",
                Count = 10
            },
            new Test
            {
                YearMonth = "17/05",
                Branch = "Melbourne",
                CIRef = "PinkyPonkies",
                Count = 19
            },
            new Test
            {
                YearMonth = "17/05",
                Branch = "Melbourne",
                CIRef = "JanglyJunglies",
                Count = 11
            },
            new Test
            {
                YearMonth = "18/05",
                Branch = "Perth",
                CIRef = "TerryTaylors",
                Count = 9
            },
            new Test
            {
                YearMonth = "18/05",
                Branch = "Perth",
                CIRef = "TimmyToolies",
                Count = 2
            },
            new Test
            {
                YearMonth = "18/05",
                Branch = "Perth",
                CIRef = "BillyBobbies",
                Count = 1
            },
            new Test
            {
                YearMonth = "18/05",
                Branch = "Sydney",
                CIRef = "RinkleRankles",
                Count = 15
            },
            new Test
            {
                YearMonth = "18/05",
                Branch = "Melbourne",
                CIRef = "PinkyPonkies",
                Count = 61
            },
            new Test
            {
                YearMonth = "18/05",
                Branch = "Melbourne",
                CIRef = "JanglyJunglies",
                Count = 99
            }
        };

        var groupedBy = Tests.GroupBy(t => t.YearMonth)
                    .SelectMany(o => o.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).Take(5));

        foreach(var c in groupedBy)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.YearMonth + " - " + c.Branch + " - " + c.CIRef + " - " + c.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me:

```
17/05 - Perth - BillyBobbies - 42
17/05 - Perth - TimmyToolies - 33
17/05 - Perth - TerryTaylors - 22
17/05 - Melbourne - PinkyPonkies - 19
17/05 - Melbourne - JanglyJunglies - 11
18/05 - Melbourne - JanglyJunglies - 99
18/05 - Melbourne - PinkyPonkies - 61
18/05 - Sydney - RinkleRankles - 15
18/05 - Perth - TerryTaylors - 9
18/05 - Perth - TimmyToolies - 2
```

as a result.

With:

```
var groupedBy = Tests.GroupBy(t => t.YearMonth)
      .SelectMany(o => o.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).Take(5));
```

we group by the `YearMonth` property, and then we order each set by its `Count` (with `Descending` so the ones with a higher `Count` are in the top) and take only the first 5 of it.

After this is done, you can add a `.ToList()` or not depending on what you want to do next.

Comment: SelectMany and the second grouping was exactly what i needed, thanks heaps, learnt a new linq function properly now too so double bonus